# Querying the nearbys restaurants locations in flutter app from firestore firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a flutter app that shows nearbys Opened restaurants for a particular Restaurant industry. So I created a database in firestore which contains: Name, latitude, longitude, isFunctional fields. Then in my flutter app i used Geolocator to obatin the location of the user. My pronlem is, I don't know how to query the database for nearby restaurants and print it as a list in my app.

I tried to ask ChatGPT but seems like the packages it's giving me are outdated. This is the code it gave me but its not running::

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
    double radius = 5000; // 5 km
    GeoPoint userLocation = GeoPoint(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('atms')
      .where('isFunctioning', isEqualTo: true)
      .where('location', isLessThan: GeoFirePoint(userLocation.latitude + radius, userLocation.longitude + radius))
      .where('location', isGreaterThan: GeoFirePoint(userLocation.latitude - radius, userLocation.longitude - radius))
      .get();
```

Comment: From the `GeoFirePoint` it seems that you're using [geoflutterfire](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire), which case a geoquery would look like: `geoRef.within(center: centerGeoPoint, radius: 50, field: 'position', strictMode: true);` See https://github.com/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire#query-geo-data

Comment: Ok thanks, let me go and try.